# Hierarchical navigations on SharePoint publishing sites

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I've got a site structure which looks like this:

- Home

  - Level 2

    - Level 3

      - Level 4

And I'm having problems with the left navigation showing correctly on a MOSS publishing site. When I'm on a page under **Level 2** The navigation should look like this:

- Level 2

  - Level 3

And when I get to a page under **Level 3** it should look like this:

- Level 2

  - Level 3

    - Level 4

But I can't seem to find a way in which the menu and data provider will do this.

How do you setup the navigation to always be starting at a fixed level but go to a depth one greater than the current depth?

Answer (score 1):

you can roll your own. Get a copy of the [moss menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2006/12/02/customizing-the-wss-3-0-moss-2007-menu-control.aspx) code, override the render method in your own control and create a solution package to release your new menu as a feature.